# How to get instance given a method of the instance?

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

```
class MyClass:
    def myMethod(self):
        pass

myInstance = MyClass()

methodReference = myInstance.myMethod
```

Now can you get a reference to `myInstance` if you now only have access to `methodReference`?

Comment: `methodReference.im_self` (`dir()` is your friend)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Python 3:

```
methodReference.__self__
```

Otherwise:

```
methodReference.im_self
```

and by a similar token, for the class:

```
methodReference.im_class
```

For this kind of code discovery you should install iPython and use tab, for instance, in your case myReference.+TAB would give:

```
In [6]: methodReference. methodReference.im_class 
methodReference.im_func   methodReference.im_self
```

Hence, you don't need to worry about remembering things so much - you know that the method is probably provided by the function object and from the suggestions that iPython gives it's usually obvious what method/attribute you're looking for.

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 3. See @dusan answer.

Comment: @Evgeny thanks - this answer was from 2013, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 39):

Try this:

```
methodReference.im_self
```

If you are using Python 3:

```
methodReference.__self__
```

Comment: old question, but this should now be the accepted answer as it's the only one to provide a solution for python3

Answer (score 1):

You can work this out yourself - have a look at the `dir` output:

```
>>> dir(mr)
['__call__', ... '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'im_class', 'im_func', 'im_self']
```

The `im_*` instances refer to attributes defined for `instance methods`...

The class it was defined in, the function code block, and the object it is bound to...

Comment: The reason I slightly prefer the iPython approach I detail above is that it hides special methods/attributes and formats on the screen slightly cleaner. But of course they're pretty equivalent in terms of functionality and your suggestion doesn't tie the user down to iPython either.