# Is it possible to recover __import__ after overwriting it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, built-in

I'm trying to write some code that is robust against `__import__` being changed, because [the Pydev debugger overrides __import__](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/8142cbfbceb1b80e1e118f7fe133d02da7f1f8bd/pydev_import_hook.py#L34).

So, I need a way of accessing the built-in `__import__` function.

```
>>> def fake_import(*args, **kwargs): pass # some other implementation here
... 
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.__import__ = fake_import
# can I recover the original value of __import__ here?
```

There are questions on SO about [recovering removed built-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13307110/509706) but in this case the global has been replaced.

Comment: save it, before replacing it

Comment: you can copy (store) it before overwriting it.

Comment: Users are using pydev's debugger -- that's not my code to change.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by getting back the original `__import__`? It is called by `ImportHookManager.do_import`, what behaviour in your code is being affected by this?

Comment: I have a multiprocessing library that serializes functions and distributes them to a cluster. I need to ensure that I serialize functions with references to `__import__` pointing to the system `__import__`, as the remote node won't have the pydev import hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat tricky issue as python will not be interested in reloading the `__builtin__` module as it hasn't changed. You will be forced to delete the `__builtin__` module so as to force python to reimport it. You can also bypass `__import__` by using `importlib` (only true in python3, in python2 `importlib` resorts to `__import__`).

```
import sys
import importlib

import __builtin__ as old_builtins

class ExampleImporter(object):
    old_import = __import__
    def __init__(self):
       self.count = 0
    def new_import(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.count += 1
        print(args, kwargs)
        return self.old_import(*args, **kwargs)
importer = ExampleImporter()

old_builtins.__import__ = importer.new_import
assert __import__ == importer.new_import

# remove builtins from modules so as to force its reimport
del sys.modules["__builtin__"]
# in python3 the following bypasses __import__ entirely, but not in python2
new_builtins = importlib.import_module("__builtin__") 
# restore initial state of __builtin__ module (will not delete new names 
# added to __builtin__)
old_builtins.__dict__.update(new_builtins.__dict__)
# Replace new __builtin__ with old __builtin__ module. Otherwise you'll end up with a 
# mess where different modules have different a __builtin__ module.
sys.modules["__builtin__"] = old_builtins
del new_builtins

assert __import__ == importer.old_import
assert importer.count == 1 # would be 0 in python3
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you link, the original `builtins.__import__` is passed to the new `ImportHookManager` instance and stored as the `_system_import` attribute.

Based on the answers to [How to get instance given a method of the instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14588905/3001761), therefore, you could do something like:

```
__import__ = __import__.im_self._system_import
```

to restore the original function. Note that the leading underscore marks this attribute as private-by-convention, though, and the implementation/attribute name could be changed without warning.

Comment: That certainly works, but it's brittle. If pydev ever renames the attribute, my code will break.

Comment: @WilfredHughes that's true, and the leading underscore suggests they'd rather you stayed away from it. You could also try using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I haven't found a way of recovering `__import__` itself, using `ihooks` I can get a function that acts as `__import__` does:

```
import ihooks
ihooks.ModuleImporter().install()

# or
works_just_like__import__ = ihooks.ModuleImporter().import_module
```

Comment: Note that `ihooks` is currently undocumented, and removed in 3.x - https://docs.python.org/2/library/undoc.html#miscellaneous-useful-utilities

Comment: Also, the [`install` method](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Lib/ihooks.py#l382) makes extensive use of `__builtin__`, so may not behave as you expect.